# 「ずっと触ってたくなるよね」: te form + たくなる

Tags: grammar, て-form, contractions

I was watching a "Chibi Maruko Chan" episode about Maruko wanting to pet a fluffy dog. In the subtitles, I saw「ずっと触ってたくなるよね」. So I understand that ずっと means "continuously," and that さわって　is the te-form of 触る. What I don't understand is what たくなるよね means. At first, I thought that たくなる　was たい (En: want) conjugated to たく when なる (En: become) is attached. However, たい is typically attached to the masu-stem of the verb, not the te-form. This is where the confusion arises.

Comment: On second thought, it could be that the caption writer made an error and that it really should be 「ずっと触っていたくなるよね」。In this case, たい would be attached to いる

Comment: I think it's possibly a reduced form of **し**たくなる. Coming from a girl with -chan in her name....it's probably shorted to "takunaru" to make it cuter. xD Examples of this shortened form: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B

Comment: Just to clarify something: Did she say this after she stopped petting the dog?

Comment: @NatsuKage Verbs conjugate to ～たい to express 'I want to ...', which conjugates like an い adjective, thus ～たくなる. ～したくなる is form specifically for する.

Comment: So Tama-chan(Maruko's friend) says this after Maruko describes how fluffy the dog is. Tama-chan would like to pet the dog continuously, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

As you guessed in your comment, ～てたくなる is a form of ～ていたくなる. (I wouldn't call it an error, though. This is a very common colloquial pronunciation.) It is not a shortened form of したくなる, because したくなる cannot even fit in these sentences to begin with.

～ていたくなる is form of ～ていたい, which is itself a form of ～ている. As ～ていたい means 'want to ～ている', ～ていたくなる means 'become wanting to ～ている'. With your example, ずっと触っていたくなる would mean '[If I pet it], I'd want to be petting it for ever'.

Comment: Could you please give a good example of ～ていたくなる and a translation? Thank you!